# Send file from Apache HTTP Client to Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http

I have the following message with a HTTP 400 while trying to send a file from Apache HTTP Client to a Spring Boot server:

> Resolved
> [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException:
> Required request part 'file' is not present]

Client code:

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(new URIBuilder(URI.create(host)).setPath("api").addParameter("id", id).build());
request.setEntity(MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
        .addPart("file", new InputStreamBody(myStream, MULTIPART_FORM_DATA))
        .build());
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

Server code:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public void send(@RequestParam("id") String id,
                 @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
// Do something
}
```

I tried with:

- Server:

  - `spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true`
  - `RequestPart` instead of `RequestParam`
- Client

  - `.setMode(BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)`
  - `addBinaryPart`

But still the same error...

Comment: Was the server-side code working when tested in a Postman?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I have tested using MultiPart with Spring Boot 3 and it was successful.

The underlying implementation of addBinaryBody still calls addPart. The difference is that addBinaryBody uses ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY during the process. This difference in ContentType from yours may be the reason for the issue.

```
try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/sample/multiPart");

            MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            builder.addBinaryBody("file", new File("someFilePath"));

            HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
            System.out.println(response.getCode());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

My Spring Boot controller

```
    @PostMapping(path = "/multiPart", produces = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity multiPartAPI(@RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
```